# Bash Grep and Send

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I'm new to bash and trying to learn a figure it out.

I have the following:

```
Sep 18 21:05:40 host kernel: Firewall: *Port Flood* IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=118.223.69.254 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=9398 PROTO=TCP SPT=9876 DPT=80 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

How can I pull the SRC IP out and pipe it to csf -d {IP HERE}

I would use something like

`sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/' /var/log/messages` right?

**EDIT:**

since the `SPT=` is the name in all could I pull that and grab the IP some how?

Comment: Did you mean GREP and SED ? And what is "csf" ? What system do you use?

Comment: Yes, grep. CSF is like IPTables.

Comment: CSF = [ConfigServer, Security & Firewall](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html)

Comment: If I had | tail at the end then it will monitor the file right?

Comment: @mike.williams You would want `tail -f /var/log/messages | script` to continuously watch the log for matches as they occur, where `script` is the answer provided by F.J.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
sed -n 's/.*SRC=\([.0-9]*\).*/\1/p' /var/log/messages | xargs csf -d
```

`xargs` will append arguments from standard input to the command.  Note that my regular expression matches the entire line with `.*` before and after the IP address, so that when you do the replacement all you are left with is the IP.

By using the `-n` option and adding `p` to the end of the sed replacement, only lines that matched the regex will be printed.

Comment: Is there a way to make it look through the file? I seem to get one entry ;/

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

with grep (GNU grep) 2.10, you can use the `P` flag, for perl compatible regex, `i` flag for casse insensitive test and the `o` flag to just display the result.

In the following, i set the pattern for a valid IP and then grep the file

```
ippattern="\b(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\b"
grep -Pio "(?<=src=)$ippattern" /var/log/messages
```

In grep whit perl compatible `-P` flag, the `(?<=XXXX)` is a back reference and is not captured by the regex. It just said that we want our pattern to be precede by XXXX. Of course you must write it before the pattern to capture.

the ippattern is a valid ip adresse. All the cases are captured.

Hope this whill help